# geth RPC API to check if geth is running in testnet or mainnet?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, testnets

Simple question: is there a way to query `geth` to know if it was launched with `--testnet` flag or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Update Dec 9 2016

Testnet was reset to the Ropsten network - [source](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/11/20/from-morden-to-ropsten/).

Use the following command to get the hash of the genesis block that will uniquely identify the two separate networks:

#### Mainnet

```
> eth.getBlock(0).hash
"0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3"
```

#### Testnet

```
> eth.getBlock(0).hash
"0x41941023680923e0fe4d74a34bdac8141f2540e3ae90623718e47d66d1ca4a2d"
```

---

## My New Answer

You can get the genesis block hash without using the `admin.nodeInfo` call that requires enabling the `admin` API via RPC, as shown in my old answer.

Use the following command to get the hash of the genesis block that will uniquely identify the two separate networks:

#### Mainnet

```
> eth.getBlock(0).hash
"0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3"
```

#### Testnet

```
> eth.getBlock(0).hash
"0x0cd786a2425d16f152c658316c423e6ce1181e15c3295826d7c9904cba9ce303"
```

---

## My Old Answer Below

You can use the `admin.nodeInfo` information to determine which network you are connected to.

#### Mainnet

```
> admin.nodeInfo.protocols.eth.genesis
"0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3"
```

#### Testnet

```
> admin.nodeInfo.protocols.eth.genesis
"0x0cd786a2425d16f152c658316c423e6ce1181e15c3295826d7c9904cba9ce303"
```

While the `admin` API is available be default over the IPC protocol, you will have to specifically enable the `admin` API over the RPC protocol if you want to use JSON-RPC to access this information.

**Just be careful of the implications of enabling the `admin` API over the RPC protocol.**

To enable the `admin` API over the RPC protocol:

```
geth --rpc --rpcaddr localhost --rpcapi "eth,net,web3,admin" console
```

To test your RPC connection's access to the admin API:

```
geth attach rpc:http://localhost:8545
> admin.nodeInfo.protocols.eth.genesis
"0xd4e56740f876aef8c010b86a40d5f56745a118d0906a34e69aec8c0db1cb8fa3"
```

Comment: Does ETH and ETC have the same genesis block? If so, is there a way to distinguish between each chain?

Comment: ETH and ETC have the same data up until block 1,919,999. ETH has a "dao-hard-fork" marker in block 1,920,000 that ETC does not have. See http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7832/give-a-summary-of-the-fork-state-changes-in-block-1920000/7840#7840

Comment: This should probably be updated to note that on the new testnet (Ropsten), the genesis block hash is '0x41941023680923e0fe4d74a34bdac8141f2540e3ae90623718e47d66d1ca4a2d'

Comment: Can you expand just a little bit on  this: "Just be careful of the implications of enabling the admin API over the RPC protocol." Or perhaps point to further information? Is this a problem if one leaves the port at its default?

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to do this with the JSON RPC APIs, unfortunately. One somewhat hacky option, however, is to call `eth_getTransactionCount` on an existing account; this will return a value <2^20 on mainnet, and >2^20 on testnet.