# Give a summary of the fork state changes in block 1920000

Tags: the-dao, hardforks

The [hard fork](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/07/20/hard-fork-completed/) during [block 1920000](http://etherscan.io/block/1920000) contained the execution of an irregular state change. For reference purposes it would be great to have a technical overview of these changes and how they were enforced.

Answer (score 7):

### Summary

The Ethereum node client software was updated to make the following changes to hard-fork the block chain in block #1,920,000 by applying the following additional block processing rules:

- Mark block #1,920,000 with the extra data `dao-hard-fork (Hex:0x64616f2d686172642d666f726b)`.
- Add the ether balance for all DAO accounts to the refund contract account, and zero out the balance for all these DAO accounts.

A total of 12,001,961.845205763407115004 ETH was swept from 58 The DAO and child DAO contracts into the refund contract at the hard-fork block #1,920,000.

There are no transactions in block #1,920,000 reflecting these balance changes, but these balance changes can be traced by reading the source code for the Ethereum node client software.

---

### Details

Here is the block number in [github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/params/dao.go#L34](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/5f55d95aea433ef97c48ae927835d833772350de/params/dao.go#L34):

```
var MainNetDAOForkBlock = big.NewInt(1920000)
```

There is an extra data marker in [github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/params/dao.go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/5f55d95aea433ef97c48ae927835d833772350de/params/dao.go#L39):

```
var DAOForkBlockExtra = common.FromHex("0x64616f2d686172642d666f726b")
```

You can see the DAO hard-fork extra data in [#1,920,000](http://etherscan.io/block/1920000):
[image]

And here is the [refund contract](http://etherscan.io/address/0xbf4ed7b27f1d666546e30d74d50d173d20bca754) address in [github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/params/dao.go#L46](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/5f55d95aea433ef97c48ae927835d833772350de/params/dao.go#L46):

```
var DAORefundContract = common.HexToAddress("0xbf4ed7b27f1d666546e30d74d50d173d20bca754")
```

And there is a list of 58 accounts to drain ([1](http://etherscan.io/address/0xd4fe7bc31cedb7bfb8a345f31e668033056b2728#code), [2](http://etherscan.io/address/0x2c19c7f9ae8b751e37aeb2d93a699722395ae18f#code), ...) in [github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/params/dao.go#L67-L417](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/5f55d95aea433ef97c48ae927835d833772350de/params/dao.go#L67-L417):

```
const daoDrainListJSON = `
[
   {
      "address":"0xd4fe7bc31cedb7bfb8a345f31e668033056b2728",
      "balance":"186cc8bfaefb7be",
      "extraBalance":"0",
      "extraBalanceAccount":"0xb3fb0e5aba0e20e5c49d252dfd30e102b171a425"
   },
   {
      "address":"0x2c19c7f9ae8b751e37aeb2d93a699722395ae18f",
      "balance":"b14e8feab1ff435",
      "extraBalance":"0",
      "extraBalanceAccount":"0xecd135fa4f61a655311e86238c92adcd779555d2"
   },
   ...
```

Here is where the fork data changes are applied to block #1,920,000 in [github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/chain_makers.go#L190-L200](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/5f55d95aea433ef97c48ae927835d833772350de/core/chain_makers.go#L190-L200) - the first section applies the extra data, and the second section calls the function to perform the forking magic:

```
func GenerateChain(config *ChainConfig, parent *types.Block, db ethdb.Database, n int, gen func(int, *BlockGen)) ([]*types.Block, []types.Receipts) {
...
if daoBlock := config.DAOForkBlock; daoBlock != nil {
    limit := new(big.Int).Add(daoBlock, params.DAOForkExtraRange)
    if h.Number.Cmp(daoBlock) >= 0 && h.Number.Cmp(limit) < 0 {
        if config.DAOForkSupport {
            h.Extra = common.CopyBytes(params.DAOForkBlockExtra)
        }
    }
}
if config.DAOForkSupport && config.DAOForkBlock != nil && config.DAOForkBlock.Cmp(h.Number) == 0 {
    ApplyDAOHardFork(statedb)
}
```

And finally, here is the function that performs the forking magic in [github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/dao.go#L63-L74](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/5f55d95aea433ef97c48ae927835d833772350de/core/dao.go#L63-L74) - the code moves the balance from each DAO account to the refund address and zeroes out the balance for those DAO accounts:

```
func ApplyDAOHardFork(statedb *state.StateDB) {
    // Retrieve the contract to refund balances into
    refund := statedb.GetOrNewStateObject(params.DAORefundContract)

    // Move every DAO account and extra-balance account funds into the refund contract
    for _, addr := range params.DAODrainList {
        if account := statedb.GetStateObject(addr); account != nil {
            refund.AddBalance(account.Balance())
            account.SetBalance(new(big.Int))
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the same type of code to set the extra data and transfer the balances in the Parity client from [github.com/ethcore/parity/ethcore/src/ethereum/ethash.rs#L131-L150](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/blob/7093651d702c90d2ec1963cc377b81dc037ff898/ethcore/src/ethereum/ethash.rs#L131-L150):

```
    if header.number >= self.ethash_params.dao_hardfork_transition &&
            header.number <= self.ethash_params.dao_hardfork_transition + 9 {
            header.extra_data = b"dao-hard-fork"[..].to_owned();
        }
        header.note_dirty();
//      info!("ethash: populate_from_parent #{}: difficulty={} and gas_limit={}", header.number, header.difficulty, header.gas_limit);
    }

    fn on_new_block(&self, block: &mut ExecutedBlock) {
        if block.fields().header.number == self.ethash_params.dao_hardfork_transition {
            // TODO: enable trigger function maybe?
//          if block.fields().header.gas_limit <= 4_000_000.into() {
                let mut state = block.fields_mut().state;
                for child in &self.ethash_params.dao_hardfork_accounts {
                    let b = state.balance(child);
                    state.transfer_balance(child, &self.ethash_params.dao_hardfork_beneficiary, &b);
                }
//          }
        }
```

A total of 12,001,961.845205763407115004 ETH was swept from the DAO contracts into the refund contract at the hard-fork block #1,920,000.

Following is the change in the balance from block #1,919,999 to block #1,920,000 in the refund contract:

```
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance("0xbf4ed7b27f1d666546e30d74d50d173d20bca754",1920000-1),"ether")
0
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance("0xbf4ed7b27f1d666546e30d74d50d173d20bca754",1920000),"ether")
12001961.845205763407115004
```

And following is the change in the balance from block #1,919,999 to block #1,920,000 in the The DAO and a few of the child DAOs:

```
// The DAO
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance("0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413",1920000-1),"ether")
1.200000000000000001
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance("0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413",1920000),"ether")
0
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance("0xd4fe7bc31cedb7bfb8a345f31e668033056b2728",1920000-1),"ether")
0.11000014249969043
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance("0xd4fe7bc31cedb7bfb8a345f31e668033056b2728",1920000),"ether")
0
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance("0x2c19c7f9ae8b751e37aeb2d93a699722395ae18f",1920000-1),"ether")
0.008519214441755701
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance("0x2c19c7f9ae8b751e37aeb2d93a699722395ae18f",1920000),"ether")
0
// Baddies DAO
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance("0x304a554a310c7e546dfe434669c62820b7d83490",1920000-1),"ether")
3642408.527612792706899331
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance("0x304a554a310c7e546dfe434669c62820b7d83490",1920000),"ether")
0
// Goodies DAOs
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance("0xb136707642a4ea12fb4bae820f03d2562ebff487",1920000-1),"ether")
7277385.711515429122911683
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance("0xb136707642a4ea12fb4bae820f03d2562ebff487",1920000),"ether")
0
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance("0x84ef4b2357079cd7a7c69fd7a37cd0609a679106",1920000-1),"ether")
598974.326560793095813484
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance("0x84ef4b2357079cd7a7c69fd7a37cd0609a679106",1920000),"ether")
0
```

Here are some github commits of interest:

- Move balances - https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/commit/14bad7e212011337d14e40c9f975efd096ab7418
- Enforce network split - https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/commit/8c20fe17bdd78a15226a3df589e8f89b48726b6e

Comment: So by "irregular," the node "blinks" during this block and accepts the balance state changes without checking for valid txn signatures. Is that right?