# A terse description of the theDAO hardfork

Tags: ether, the-dao, hardforks, ethereum-classic, blockchain-fork

As I understand it, at block 1920000 the blockchain was forked and there are now two blockchain strands; ETH (hard-forked) or ETC (non-hard-forked) blockchain. This is known as "the DAO hardfork".

Please, in terse language;

- describe what was was done
- compare the size/other useful metrics of
  the two blockchains (as of Sept 2016)
- state the basic
  configuration changes the average user must make to switch between
  the two chains

Note, I'm not interested (in this question) in why this was done, just a consise explanation of what has been done what the current status is.

I have also seen this related question and answer:

[Give a summary of the fork state changes in block 1920000](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/7832/820)

Comment: You cannot fork existing blockchains to "make another one out of it" To understand read SZABO 1998, especially paragraph 8

Comment: thanks, you mean this? http://szabo.best.vwh.net/msc.html

Comment: Please can you quote the chapter in the answer and add a clear ling to the paper ?

Comment: @NicolasMassart Alas, user4206 seems to have unregistered.

Comment: @atomh33ls it was à fast one...

Comment: I think user4206 might be suggesting Nick Szabo's Bit gold paper(?) of 1998. I can find some [references](fascinating) but cannot find the source... fascinating.

Comment: This answers in part; https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/07/20/hard-fork-completed/